# elegant map over 2D list

Tags: python, python-3.9

What's an elegant way to map `func` over each value in a 2D list?

The best I have so far:

```
result = [[func(value) for value in row] for row in grid]
```

It's a shame I have to nest square brackets, and have a lot of list comprehensions. Is there a less verbose or more elegant way?

```
result = map2d(func, grid)
```

Comment: I think your initial approach is obvious, readable, error free and short enough for the task at hand. It can be refactored to a "map2d" func, but then, just create this func and put that code in, like in:  `map2d= lambda func, data: [[func(element) for element in row] for row in data]`

Comment: `[list(map(func, row)) for row in grid]` ?

Answer (score 3):

"It's a shame I have to nest square brackets" - No it's not, it's a Pythonic way to go and makes it clear that result is a list of lists (as long as you don't go overboard with even more nested list comprehensions). If you really don't want to see that in the code just wrap it in your own function:

```
def map2d(func, grid):
    return [[func(value) for value in row] for row in grid]
result = map2d(func, grid)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your initial approach is obvious, readable, error free and short enough for the task at hand. It can be refactored to a "map2d" func, but then, just create this func and put that code in, like in: map2d= lambda func, data: [[func(element) for element in row] for row in data]

What might feel strange about nestign the brackets is that the "list inside list" approach for 2D data, although straightforward, have some drawbacks.

It is easy to have other forms of 2D data structures in Python, by implementing a new class with custom `__getitem__`, `__setitem__` and `__delitem__` methods that will give allow the syntax `mydata[x, y]`. And then, if you derive your class, for example, [from `collections.abc.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes), you can iterate over it, or over the return of `mydata.items`to reach all data points with a linear `for` loop.

another advantage is that a custom class can them know about its width X height and check boundaries - and just return a default value for unfilled elments, working as a sparse matrix.

Another approach is simply using a dictionary, with no class creation, for your 2D data, and retrieve data with the `get` method in order to have a default value at hand:

```
from random import randint
W, H = 10, 10
grid = dict()
# fill in data:
for x in range(W):
   for y in range(H):
      grid[x,y] = randint(0, 100)
# loop through all values:
for coord in grid:
     print(grid[coord])
     # change value:
     grid[coord] = new_value(grid[coord])
```

This approach won't let you do "map" with a onelinet, but by explictly calling in `grid.__setitem__` though. By using a custom class, like suggested above, you can simply add a `.map` method that will do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use mal twice, not sure though if this is more elegant as compared to your solution

```py
result = list(map(lambda row: list(map(func, row)), grid))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong about the nested listcomp, it is my preferred solution. But you could "vectorize" the function you want to apply.

```
def vectorize(f):
    def f_vectorized(args): # iterable args, check against str in real code
        return [f(x) for x in args]
    return f_vectorized

func_vec = vectorize(func)
result = list(map(func_vec, grid))
```

Demo:

```
>>> def func(x):
...     return x + 1
>>> grid = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> func_vec = vectorize(func)
>>> func_vec_vec = vectorize(func_vec)
>>> list(map(func_vec, grid))
[[2, 3], [4, 5]]
>>> func_vec_vec(grid)
[[2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own -

```
def map2d(func, grid):
    out_grid = []
    for row in grid:
        out_grid.append(list(map(func, row)))
    return out_grid

x = [[1, 1, 2], [2, 2, 3], [3, 4, 3]]
map2d(lambda z: z**2, x)
#[[1, 1, 4], [4, 4, 9], [9, 16, 9]]
```